# Love hats; slightly miffed. Why no hat for getting gold badge?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

Is there a reason, or was it merely oversight, that no hat is awarded for getting a gold badge?

There is a hat for getting a silver badge (which I have and like), but there should be an extravagant lollapalooza of a hat or fascinator for getting a gold badge!  Which I have just got (for the type of answer that tchrist routinely inveighs against.  Oh, the guilt!)

Comment: I'll make you a deal: you can trade me your gold thingy for any one of the following hats. Your choice: ⛑.

Comment: @Dan Bron Thank you.  It is a generous offer.  However, I cannot permit you, in a moment of weakness, to deviate from your credo that rep points and such-like have no real value.  You would hate me, and yourself, tomorrow.

Comment: Oh, I don't want the gold thingy.  I was gonna trash it (it would make tchrist happier, SWR is very nearly a 4 letter word).  But I didn't want you to feel the hat was an act of charity.  It's an equal exchange of imaginary value, made of bits and fantasies.

Comment: Oh I was also upset about this. I got two damn gold badges right as winter bash started and then... nothing. There was one last year but i didn’t get it till late in the festivities. I really thought this would be the year I’d make everyone jealous of how fashionable I am from the get go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all official, but my vague understanding is that to keep things fresh and interesting, they try not to repeat hat-earning criteria year-to-year; so any activity that was worth a hat last year probably isn't this year.  (But it may well be again in another year or three.)